# Sublime Text 4 MDX Color Syntax Package

Tags: syntax-highlighting, text-editor, sublimetext4

Any package that I could be missing, for MDX color syntax highlighting, in Sublime Text 4, which works correctly?

Tried the following but both have broken coloring, as in imports after 1st one showing as plain text, same with exported constants, etc.

- [MDX Syntax Highlighting](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MDX%20Syntax%20Highlighting) (which is a port of the below)
- [Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel)

Issue illustration (this is with MDX Syntax Highlighting):
[image]

[Package control offers nothing else, at least under MDX keyword.](https://packagecontrol.io/search/MDX)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your color scheme to something that covers more scopes. For example, here is your code with Mariana, the default color scheme for new installations of Sublime Text 4:

[image: MDX with Mariana]

Here it is using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (full disclosure: I am the author):

[image: MDX with Neon Color Scheme]

And here it is with [Monokai Pro](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Monokai%20Pro):

[image: MDX with Monokai Pro]

You are most likely using an old color scheme from Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm using Monokai Pro, just tried with Mariana to double check and the colors are off in the exact same places as with Monokai. Will try re-installing Sublime & packages from scratch, which is a pain, but to discard any chance other packages could be conflicting. Btw, I took that screenshot from here, so guess I'm not alone https://github.com/jonsuh/mdx-sublime/issues/3

Comment: @Syden I use a slightly modified Markdown syntax, so I wonder if that has something to do with it.